# Angular - How to draw on PDF file embedded in HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: html, angular, typescript, canvas, pdf.js

I render the pages of my pdf one by one on a HtmlCanvasElement and I want to draw in each page but the drawing doesn't get saved on the page and it gets carryed to the other pages like it is an overlay.

Then I want to send back the edited pdf to the backend and save it in filesystem.

This is how I firstly load the pdf:

```
`loadPDF() {
  this.commessaService.uploadPDF().subscribe(pdf =>{
  new Response(pdf).arrayBuffer()
    .then( arr => {
    this.openPDF(arr)
  });
 })
}`


`async openPDF(pdf : ArrayBuffer){
  var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdf);
  (async () => {
    const pdfToUp = await loadingTask.promise

  this.thePDF = pdfToUp;
  this.numPages = pdfToUp.numPages;

  this.thePDF.getPage(this.currPage).then( page => {
    this.handlePages(page);
  });
  })();
}`


`handlePages(page : any) {
  const scale = 1.5;
  const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale })
  const canvas = (<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas"));
  canvas.style.display = "block";
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  canvas.width = Math.floor(viewport.width );
  canvas.height = Math.floor(viewport.height );
  canvas.style.width = Math.floor(viewport.width) + "px";
  canvas.style.height = Math.floor(viewport.height) + "px";

  page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
}`
```

This is how i load the next pages:

```
`nextPage(){
  if(this.thePDF != null && (this.currPage + 1) < this.numPages){
  this.currPage++;
  this.thePDF.getPage(this.currPage).then( page => {
  this.handlePages(page);
 });
 }
}`
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: up up up up up up up up

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time.  Do you know any tutorial that I can follow about it?  My task is drawing on a pdf essentially.

Comment: @FrancescoNotte did you manage to get it working? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Of course, i did it! 
I hope you solved it because I no longer have that project